# Android: Updating fields for ParseUsers

Tags: android, android-activity, parse-platform

I am using ParseUser for user management. Having the username (unique), I planned to query the User class to identify the user and then put a new score to the "score" field, just like a Leaderboard. Coded as follows:

### Code:

```
public void update_user_score(String username, int original_score, int add)
{
    final int new_score = original_score + add;  
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("username", username);
    query.setLimit(1);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() 
    {
          public void done(final ParseObject object, ParseException e) 
          {
            if (e == null) 
            {
                object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() 
                {
                    public void done(ParseException e) 
                    {
                        object.put("score", new_score);                                 
                        object.saveInBackground();                                      
                        onBackPressed();                            
                    }
                });
            }
          }
    });
}
```

Situation:
It states that `The type new FindCallback(){} must implement the inherited abstract method FindCallback.done(List, ParseException)` . I have tried that `FindCallback.done` and found it unsucessful.

### Question:

I would like to ask how the other fields of the user be updated with the username given? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the parse documentation said,

The ParseUser class is secured by default. Data stored in a ParseUser can only be modified by that user. By default, the data can still be read by any client. Thus, some ParseUser objects are authenticated and can be modified, whereas others are read-only.

Specifically, you are not able to invoke any of the save or delete type methods unless the ParseUser was obtained using an authenticated method, like logIn or signUp. This ensures that only the user can alter their own data.

The following illustrates this security policy:

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.logIn("my_username", "my_password");
user.setUsername("my_new_username"); // attempt to change username
user.saveInBackground(); // This succeeds, since the user was authenticated on the device

// Get the user from a non-authenticated manner
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.getInBackground(user.getObjectId(), new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
  public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
    object.setUsername("another_username");

    // This will throw an exception, since the ParseUser is not authenticated
    object.saveInBackground();
  }
});
```

please go through this link [Reference](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#users)

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out that "ParseUser class is secured by default. Data stored in a ParseUser can only be modified by that user." which I discovered subsequently as I found I can amend my own score after login but cant if logged out.The original intention is that I would like to create a leaderboard directly using the ParseUser table. If then I need to create a custom Leaderboard table and create same users referencing from ParseUser to do editing on data (scores)?

Comment: Yes, in your parse db, you can create a clone of ParseUser table and can do make reference from that clone table in your app instead of ParseUser. You can also managed CRUD operation by reference clone table.

Comment: You can do all db operation on cloned table like create, read, update, delete.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void update_user_score(String username, int original_score, int add)
{
  final int new_score = original_score + add;  
  ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
  query.whereEqualTo("username", username);
  query.setLimit(1);

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() 
{
      public void done(final ParseUser object, ParseException e) 
      {
        if (e == null) 
        {   
            object.put("score", new_score);
            object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() 
            {
                public void done(ParseException e) 
                {

                    if(e==null)                                   
                    onBackPressed();                            
                }
            });
        }
      }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your question is; you want to find the user entry in user table via using the specified user id  and update the score field. First suggestion, instead of findInBackground use getFirstInBackground. Following that check the returned user object if not null perfrom the user update operation. Then call saveInBackground. saveInBackground is used for perfroming actions when the save is succesful. In your code, I see that you try to save the object in done method again.  Also, one suggestion is that control the ACL.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.getFirstInBackground(someUserId, new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // No error e is null
            // check user object
            if (user == null) {
                // no user , error
            } else {
                // perfrom save operation
                //  put score field
                // call save in background
                // in done method update UI for example.
            }
        } else {
            // Something went wrong.
        }
    }
});
```